# How to recognize move operation with FindFirstChangeNotification?

Tags: winapi

The API method signals deletion, creation, modification, but not "moved from/ to".
Is it possible to get the information where from (or where to) a file is moved?

Comment: A move is a deletion from the source and a creation in the destination.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that ;-) So - in the case of source and dest are both watched - I have to match it by myself? And - if only one of it (source or dest) is watched ... how do I get the other?

Comment: You can't get the other if you're not watching it, and yes, you have to match it yourself. There is no *move* notification. You get a deletion from source followed by a creation in destination, as I said before. If you're not watching both, then only one of them is relevant to you. :-)

Comment: OK for the case of both (source, dest) in the watch list - I have to match. But not OK if only one of them (say the dest) is watched. It is very well relevant for me then (believe me ;) where the file is moved from - and I don't have any idea where this might be. This is my scenario.

Comment: Windows itself knows it is moving (= change directory entry). And if you take Google's Picasa for example, it is so quick that it seems to get the info somehow. Maybe there is another way for my problem?

Comment: The dest file should be created before the source file is deleted, in case the move fails. Moving a file within a volume is fast as the file is not physically moved, just references to the file in the source and dest folders are updated. You could use a file ID from `GetFileInformationByHandle()` to check if the source and dest files refer to the same ID. Or, since a move on a volume is just a rename, a `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME` notification from `ReadDirectoryChangesW()` should include old and new paths. Moving a file across volumes requires a physical copy, so this won't work for that.